# how to convert sqlite db to mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

This my sqlite database i want to chang this db to mysql db

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'ifse_content';
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ifse_content USING fts3(url, title, keywords, desc, content, tokenize=porter);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'ifse_content_content';
CREATE TABLE 'ifse_content_content'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'c0url', 'c1title', 'c2keywords', 'c3desc', 'c4content');
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'ifse_content_segdir';
CREATE TABLE 'ifse_content_segdir'(level INTEGER,idx INTEGER,start_block INTEGER,leaves_end_block INTEGER,end_block INTEGER,root BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(level, idx));
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'ifse_content_segments';
CREATE TABLE 'ifse_content_segments'(blockid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, block BLOB);
```

how to convert this sqlite database to mysql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit too long for a comment

In sqlite you don't have to specify types for columns in create statements but in mysql you need to. Looking at your tables, it's not possible for anyone to figure out what the column types are so no one can give you a complete answer. But we can give you some hints.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ifse_content USING fts3(url, title, keywords, desc, content, tokenize=porter);
```

This creates a table with [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) support something like

```
CREATE TABLE ifse_content( ...
   content varchar(255),
   ..
   FULLTEXT ids(content));
```

For creating the other tables, specify the column types and remove the single quotes. They should work without too much trouble.